# ActiveMQ HA On failover

Tags: activemq-classic, high-availability

Does ActiveMQ cluster (master-slave) offer high availability on failover mode? 
I am publishing messages on a topic but when I kill active node and my consumer connect to the other node It loses several messages.
I need only topic mode, because I need to have different pods consuming messages at the same time. We have made test with durable messages and subscriptions wit we got the same problem.

If ActiveMQ doesn't support this functionality, is there other broker that could do this?

We have used Spring boot to develop sender and consumer apps.

**SENDER:**

To send messages we used and API REST that sends 5000 messages to a topic. If some convertAndSend fails (ActiveMQ node 1 killed) we retry it until the failover.

This is my sender class:

```
@RestController
public class RestApiController {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/produce")
    public String produce() {
        String result = "Done";
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
            boolean repetir = true;
            while (repetir) {
                try {
                    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("TestTopic", "Message " + i);
                    repetir = false;
                    result = "Done";
                } catch (JmsException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    result = "ERROR";
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is de sender's application.properties:

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=failover:(tcp://172.18.13.45:61616,tcp://172.18.13.45:61626)?initialReconnectDelay=1&backup=true spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin 
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true 
server.port=8081
```

**CONSUMER:**

This is my listener class:

```
@Service
public class ContactTransactionReceiver {

    @JmsListener(destination = "TestTopic")
    public void receiveMessageSendMessage(Message message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(((TextMessage) message).getText());
    }
}
```

This is the consumer's application.properties:

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=failover:(tcp://172.18.13.45:61616,tcp://172.18.13.45:61626)?initialReconnectDelay=1&backup=true
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true
server.port=8082
```

**ACTIVEMQ NODE 1**

We have included this configuration in activemq.xml for HA, that refers to node2:

```
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>
    <networkConnectors>
        <networkConnector uri="static:(tcp://172.18.13.45:61616,tcp://172.18.13.45:61626)" />
    </networkConnectors>
```

We have proved too master-slave:

```
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>
    <networkConnectors>
        <networkConnector uri="masterslave:(tcp://172.18.13.45:61616,tcp://172.18.13.45:61626)" />
    </networkConnectors>
```

**ACTIVEMQ NODE 2**

We have included this configuration in activemq.xml for HA, that refers to node2:

```
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>
    <networkConnectors>
        <networkConnector uri="static:(tcp://172.18.13.45:61626,tcp://172.18.13.45:61616)" />
    </networkConnectors>
```

We have proved too master-slave:

```
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>
    <networkConnectors>
        <networkConnector uri="masterslave:(tcp://172.18.13.45:61626,tcp://172.18.13.45:61616)" />
    </networkConnectors>
```

You can find the full code and ActiveMQ configuration files in:

https://github.com/PedroRamirezTOR/ActiveMQ-HA-Sender-Consumer.git

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UoZK.jpg) Please find enclosed MQ HA architecture which describes about MQ HA

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ 5.x does support high availability via a master-slave configuration. See [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/masterslave.html) for more details.

Comment: Hi Justin! We have seen the documentation and we have implemented master-slave. But when we kill (not stop) the active mode, some of the messages are lost so aren't consumed. Is this normal?

Comment: I would *not* expect that behavior since the whole point of high availability is to prevent message loss in the case of a failure.  You should update your question with the full details of your entire use-case (including broker configuration, client code, and testing procedures).

Comment: Ok thanks Justin! We are going to prepare all with details. It would be great if you could review it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Justin! I included more details about our problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in your xmls that both master & slave are referring to a local KashaDB.  I believe to have true HA Failover, you need to reference a shared network drive.

http://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave

```
<persistenceAdapter>
  <kahaDB directory="/sharedFileSystem/sharedBrokerData"/>
</persistenceAdapter>
```